# SSIS How to use existing C# method in other Script Task module

Tags: c#, ssis

I created a Script Task in SSIS using C# language. There is a method in this Script task:

```cs
public int FindSum(int num1, int num2)
{
   int result;
   result = num1+num2

   return result;
}
```

How can I re-use this `FindSum` method in other Script Task module in the same SSIS project?

Comment: This is a tough one. I believe you have to publish your class library into the GAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use uses a script many times, It's a good idea to write a custom task instead of using the Script task. This [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/task/developing-a-custom-task?view=sql-server-ver16) describes how to develop a Custom Task.

**Another way to reuse a function:**
Create a .NET library to register the DLL in GAC. When the DLL is registered in GAC, you can reference the library in Script Task or Script Component. This [Link](https://matrixpost.net/load-an-custom-assembly-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-script-task-that-is-not-or-cannot-be-stored-in-the-gac/) illustrates how to Load a custom Assembly in SSIS Script Task.